# How to auto inject mocked types defined in test parameters into SUT using AutoFixture AutoMoq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

Let's say that I have the following code example:

```
public interface IBar
{
   string GetMessage();
}

public class Foo
{
   private readonly IBar bar;

   public Foo(IBar bar)
   {
      this.bar = bar;
   }

   public string Prefix { get; set; }

   public string RetrieveMessage()
   {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Prefix)) return string.Empty;
      return $"{Prefix} {this.bar.GetMessage()}";
   }
}
```

I currently have a test that looks like the following:

```
[Test, AutoMoqData]
public void TestThatIHaveToManuallyCreateSUT(Mock<IBar> mockBar)
{
   // Arrange
   mockBar.Setup(x => x.GetMessage()).Returns("World");
   Foo sut = new Foo(mockBar.Object)
   {
      Prefix = "Hello",
   };

   // Act
   var actual = sut.RetrieveMessage();

   // Assert
   Assert.AreEqual($"{sut.Prefix} World", actual);
   mockBar.Verify(x => x.GetMessage(), Times.Once());
}
```

Which works fine, but it has the issue of manually needing the SUT to be created in the test. This becomes a problem when I have code that depends on properties needing to have some data in them, and needing to always remember to initialize the property with some value (as is the case with `Foo.Prefix`).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to define the test in the following way:

```
[Test, AutoMoqData]
public void TestWhereAutoDataCreatesTheSUT(Mock<IBar> mockBar, Foo sut)
{
   // Arrange
   mockBar.Setup(x => x.GetMessage()).Returns("World");

   // Act
   var actual = sut.RetrieveMessage();

   // Assert
   Assert.AreEqual($"{sut.Prefix} World", actual);
   mockBar.Verify(x => x.GetMessage(), Times.Once());
}
```

Where the SUT is automatically created with the `mockBar` instance, and I can then use it further in the test.

The code above doesn't work as it will auto mock a new instance `IBar`, and not give me access to the underlying mock object.

I don't have anything fancy in my `AutoMoqDataAttribute`:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
   public AutoMoqDataAttribute() : base(() => new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true }))
   {
   }
}
```

But I would figure if there's any setup that needs to happen in order to achieve this, it would be here.

Is there a way to auto inject mocked types defined in test parameters into SUT using AutoFixture AutoMoq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [following article](https://docs.insightarchitectures.com/unit-testing-csharp/autofixture/combining-autofixture-with-nunit-and-moq) I would suggest refactoring your test

```
[Test, AutoMoqData]
public void TestWhereAutoDataCreatesTheSUT([Frozen]IBar bar, Foo sut) {
    // Arrange
    Mock<IBar> mockBar = Mock.Get(bar);
    mockBar.Setup(x => x.GetMessage()).Returns("World");

    // Act
    var actual = sut.RetrieveMessage();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual($"{sut.Prefix} World", actual);
    mockBar.Verify(x => x.GetMessage(), Times.Once());
}
```